# vue create throws 651 error that i can't figure out

Tags: node.js, vue.js, npm

I tried to research this error but couldn't find any resource. Here is the issue the vue was installed using `npm install -g @vue/cli` 
the version 3.5.1 is installed. also running the node version v11.12.0.
When i try to create new vue by running `vue create d3-example` getting an error

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:651
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'fs-extra'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:649:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:575:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:705:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:14:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/lib/create.js:1:12)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:799:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:810:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:666:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:606:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:598:3)
```

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Execute 'npm install --save fs-extra' in your shell and try again.

Comment: Thank you for the response...I solved it by reinstalling node through brew install node